# jQuery error only in IE8 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

Tags: jquery

I'm using **jQuery v2.0.1** on a web page that contains a grid, and there is an 'Search' ImageButton at the footer. At grid_RowCommond event, I will use the below script to show the search result in a pop up, and when users click on one of the search result, the selected result will returned to the footer row at the parent page and the pop up will be closed. I tested this function on IE10, which works perfectly until the users feedback that they saw the javascript error at the bottom of IE8.

Please help me.

```
protected void grid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Search")
    {
        TextBox txtNo = grid.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNo") as TextBox;

        System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        s.Append("<script language='javascript' id='SearchResult'> " );
        s.Append("var WinSettings = 'dialogHeight:400px ; dialogWidth: 550px ;center: Yes ;resizable: No;status: no'; ");
        s.Append("javascript: var windowReturnValue =window.showModalDialog('Search.aspx?car_no=" + txtNo.Text.Trim().ToUpper() + "','',WinSettings);");

        s.Append("$('#" + txtNo.ClientID + "').val(windowReturnValue) ;"); 
        s.Append("</script > ");

        if ((!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("SearchResult")))
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SearchResult", s.ToString());
        }                     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery 2.x has removed IE8 support, use instead lastest 1.x stable version of jQuery; 1.10.2

Answer (score 0):

Jquery 2. x dropped IE 8 support

for reference please refer the below link

http://jquery.com/browser-support/